# Laravel cross domain cookie

Tags: laravel, cookies, cross-domain

Is it possible to send cookie from **X** domain to **Y** domain using redirect?
When I send cookies from domain **X** to domain **X** it works with using :

```
return redirect($url)->withCookie(...);
```

I have tried using :

```
return redirect()->away($url)->withCookie(...);
```

but it does not work.

```
I need to enable something in framework?
Y domain is blocking sending cookies?
```

Comment: on same host..?

Comment: I will say something that I'm not entirely sure (correct me if I'm wrong): sending cookies from one domain to another is not possible due to security. Can you imagine me sending a cookie with a malicious intent to Facebook for example? The best you could do is: send a parameter in the URL and domain Y get this parameter and create a new cookie with this parameter